# OSX Server - My Administrator password expired?

Tags: macos, passwords, administrator, osx-server

In our office we run an OSX Server (10.7.5). Today I needed to log onto the server to adjust some settings. I attempted to use Apple's Remote Desktop tool as I usually do. When attempting to connect it said "Authentication Failed".

At first I thought that someone hacked into the server and changed the Administrator password...

Next I went directly to the server hardware with a physical monitor and attempted to login using Administrator. Instead of denying me access it told me my password was expired and I needed to change it.... So I did so and was able to successfully log into the server.

So, I had no idea that in OSX Server an Administrator's password could expire. When I open the  Server application and look at Administrator user, when I right click and look at User Info, it says that the password policies only apply toward non-admin users.

So where in OSX Server is the password policy for Administrators?